# Declare a DataSet for DataGridView CellFormatting

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, dataset

Im trying to change a row color in datagridview but the code that used to work for me needs a dataset. This is the code that i use to fill my datagridview

```
    Dim sql As String
    sql = "SELECT * FROM [product info]"
    Dim adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(sql, strcon)
    Dim dt As New DataTable("[product info]")
    adapter.Fill(dt)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt

    Dim sql1 As String
    sql1 = "SELECT * FROM [product info]"
    Dim adapter1 As New OleDbDataAdapter(sql1, strcon)
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(sql1, strcon)
    strcon.Open()
    Dim myreader As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
    myreader.Read()

    strcon.Close()
```

How can i declare a dataset within this line of codes?

Answer (score 0):

```
    Dim sql As String
    sql = "SELECT * FROM [product info]"
    Dim adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(sql, strcon)
    Dim ds As New DataSet("[product info]")
    adapter.Fill(ds)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = ds

    Dim sql1 As String
    sql1 = "SELECT * FROM [product info]"
    Dim adapter1 As New OleDbDataAdapter(sql1, strcon)
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(sql1, strcon)
    strcon.Open()
    Dim myreader As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
    myreader.Read()

strcon.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim ds as New Dataset("product_info")
ds.Tables.Add(dt)
```

Add these row after you filled data to datatable dt